# Browser does not fetch page or link not working if link is to current page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Browser does not fetch page or link not working if link is to current page. In the code sample below, I have a link (in a menu). If the user is currently in the GetData page, and the user clicks on the "Get Data" link again, nothing happens. The browser does not attempt to retrieve the page. I've monitored this in IE8 and Chrome developer tools. Any idea?

```
//Link
<a href="@Url.Action("GetData", "Data")"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i>Get Data</a>

//Controller has a custom Authorization attribute
[AuthorizeRedirect]
public class DataController : Controller

// Controller Action Invoked
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetData(int parameter)
{
   ...
}
```

I created a test web application from scratch and the page is refreshed even when I click on a link to a page that is currently loaded.

I compared both response headers from the application and the test application and noticed a difference in the cache header.

My application contains the following:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
```

While my test application contains only the following:

```
Cache-Control:private
```

Additional Info: I am using Angular JS and Bootstrap client side.

Comment: Looks like this issue is related to ng-grid. I created another controller and corresponding page with angular js and no ng-grid and it page is refreshed upon clicking a link to the current page. When I added a simple ng-grid, clicking on the link does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I thing it happens because of caching of Browser. Clear the Browser cache and try again. hope that i will help

Comment: I have cleared browser cache several times and same behaviour occurs

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the Headers inside the `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` event in `Global.asax`?

You can use `Response.Cache.SetCacheability` rather than setting the Headers directly.*

```
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

Alternative way by setting the Headers manually.

```
void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
```

If you don't want no caching everywhere then you might try something like this:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Comment: I've done both already but still doesn't work. What's odd is that in my application, I created a new Controller (with the same class and action level attributes), added a new page. but on the new page/controller, the page is refreshing if I click on the link that points to the page I am currently at.